# SSRS Report has broken border when adding image to table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I'm working on a SSRS report. When I export it to pdf it works fine but when it comes to Word it's error on border.

I export to Word file, open in a browser, set the View to Reading View and here is the result: broken border near Text3.

[image]

Please anyone here can support. I spend 2 days working on it and still can't solve the issue.

Thank you very much.

I add my TestReportWithImage.rdl.

Sorry I have to replace image embedded code with "..." to reduce the body character limit so I can post the question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report MustUnderstand="df" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:df="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition/defaultfontfamily">
  <df:DefaultFontFamily>Segoe UI</df:DefaultFontFamily>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="IM">
      <DataSourceReference>IM</DataSourceReference>
      <rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>41c23baa-9da7-4cdf-8ec2-6777e319d897</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
 
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix8">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>
                <TablixColumn>
                  <Width>3.0625in</Width>
                </TablixColumn>
              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox43">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value>Text1</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <Color>White</Color>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox33</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                              <Width>0.25pt</Width>
                            </Border>
                            <BackgroundColor>Black</BackgroundColor>
                            <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                            <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>1.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox47">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value />
                                  <Style>
                                    <Color>White</Color>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox39</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                              <Width>0.25pt</Width>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>0.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox53">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value> Text2</Value>
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontSize>11pt</FontSize>
                                    <Color>White</Color>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox41</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                              <Width>0.25pt</Width>
                            </Border>
                            <BackgroundColor>Black</BackgroundColor>
                            <VerticalAlign>Middle</VerticalAlign>
                            <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>1.25in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Textbox Name="Textbox62">
                          <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                          <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                          <Paragraphs>
                            <Paragraph>
                              <TextRuns>
                                <TextRun>
                                  <Value />
                                  <Style>
                                    <FontWeight>Normal</FontWeight>
                                    <Color>White</Color>
                                  </Style>
                                </TextRun>
                              </TextRuns>
                              <Style />
                            </Paragraph>
                          </Paragraphs>
                          <rd:DefaultName>Textbox62</rd:DefaultName>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>Solid</Style>
                              <Width>0.25pt</Width>
                            </Border>
                            <BottomBorder>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                            </BottomBorder>
                            <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Textbox>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
                <TablixRow>
                  <Height>1.88578in</Height>
                  <TablixCells>
                    <TablixCell>
                      <CellContents>
                        <Tablix Name="Tablix4">
                          <TablixBody>
                            <TablixColumns>
                              <TablixColumn>
                                <Width>0.03125in</Width>
                              </TablixColumn>
                              <TablixColumn>
                                <Width>1.5in</Width>
                              </TablixColumn>
                              <TablixColumn>
                                <Width>1.5in</Width>
                              </TablixColumn>
                              <TablixColumn>
                                <Width>0.03125in</Width>
                              </TablixColumn>
                            </TablixColumns>
                            <TablixRows>
                              <TablixRow>
                                <Height>0.38578in</Height>
                                <TablixCells>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Textbox Name="Textbox1">
                                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                        <Paragraphs>
                                          <Paragraph>
                                            <TextRuns>
                                              <TextRun>
                                                <Value />
                                                <Style>
                                                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </Style>
                                              </TextRun>
                                            </TextRuns>
                                            <Style />
                                          </Paragraph>
                                        </Paragraphs>
                                        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>None</Style>
                                          </Border>
                                          <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Textbox>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Textbox Name="Textbox64">
                                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                        <Paragraphs>
                                          <Paragraph>
                                            <TextRuns>
                                              <TextRun>
                                                <Value>Text3</Value>
                                                <Style>
                                                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </Style>
                                              </TextRun>
                                            </TextRuns>
                                            <Style />
                                          </Paragraph>
                                        </Paragraphs>
                                        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox64</rd:DefaultName>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>None</Style>
                                          </Border>
                                          <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Textbox>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Textbox Name="Textbox78">
                                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                        <Paragraphs>
                                          <Paragraph>
                                            <TextRuns>
                                              <TextRun>
                                                <Value>Text4</Value>
                                                <Style>
                                                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </Style>
                                              </TextRun>
                                            </TextRuns>
                                            <Style />
                                          </Paragraph>
                                        </Paragraphs>
                                        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox78</rd:DefaultName>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>None</Style>
                                          </Border>
                                          <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Textbox>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Textbox Name="Textbox3">
                                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                        <Paragraphs>
                                          <Paragraph>
                                            <TextRuns>
                                              <TextRun>
                                                <Value />
                                                <Style>
                                                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                                                </Style>
                                              </TextRun>
                                            </TextRuns>
                                            <Style>
                                              <TextAlign>Left</TextAlign>
                                            </Style>
                                          </Paragraph>
                                        </Paragraphs>
                                        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox3</rd:DefaultName>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>None</Style>
                                          </Border>
                                          <VerticalAlign>Bottom</VerticalAlign>
                                          <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Textbox>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                </TablixCells>
                              </TablixRow>
                              <TablixRow>
                                <Height>1.5in</Height>
                                <TablixCells>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Textbox Name="Textbox2">
                                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                        <Paragraphs>
                                          <Paragraph>
                                            <TextRuns>
                                              <TextRun>
                                                <Value />
                                                <Style />
                                              </TextRun>
                                            </TextRuns>
                                            <Style />
                                          </Paragraph>
                                        </Paragraphs>
                                        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox2</rd:DefaultName>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>None</Style>
                                          </Border>
                                          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Textbox>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Image Name="Image6">
                                        <Source>Embedded</Source>
                                        <Value>Untitled1</Value>
                                        <Sizing>FitProportional</Sizing>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>None</Style>
                                          </Border>
                                          <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Image>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Image Name="Image7">
                                        <Source>Embedded</Source>
                                        <Value>Untitled1</Value>
                                        <Sizing>FitProportional</Sizing>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>None</Style>
                                          </Border>
                                          <PaddingLeft>4pt</PaddingLeft>
                                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Image>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                  <TablixCell>
                                    <CellContents>
                                      <Textbox Name="Textbox4">
                                        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                                        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                                        <Paragraphs>
                                          <Paragraph>
                                            <TextRuns>
                                              <TextRun>
                                                <Value />
                                                <Style />
                                              </TextRun>
                                            </TextRuns>
                                            <Style />
                                          </Paragraph>
                                        </Paragraphs>
                                        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox4</rd:DefaultName>
                                        <Style>
                                          <Border>
                                            <Style>None</Style>
                                          </Border>
                                          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                                          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                                          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                                          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                                        </Style>
                                      </Textbox>
                                    </CellContents>
                                  </TablixCell>
                                </TablixCells>
                              </TablixRow>
                            </TablixRows>
                          </TablixBody>
                          <TablixColumnHierarchy>
                            <TablixMembers>
                              <TablixMember />
                              <TablixMember />
                              <TablixMember />
                              <TablixMember />
                            </TablixMembers>
                          </TablixColumnHierarchy>
                          <TablixRowHierarchy>
                            <TablixMembers>
                              <TablixMember>
                                <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
                              </TablixMember>
                              <TablixMember>
                                <Group Name="Details" />
                              </TablixMember>
                            </TablixMembers>
                          </TablixRowHierarchy>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                              <Width>0.25pt</Width>
                            </Border>
                            <PaddingLeft>6pt</PaddingLeft>
                            <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                            <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                            <PaddingBottom>6pt</PaddingBottom>
                          </Style>
                        </Tablix>
                      </CellContents>
                    </TablixCell>
                  </TablixCells>
                </TablixRow>
              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
            <TablixColumnHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixColumnHierarchy>
            <TablixRowHierarchy>
              <TablixMembers>
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
                <TablixMember />
              </TablixMembers>
            </TablixRowHierarchy>
            <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
            <Top>0.19519in</Top>
            <Left>0.66146cm</Left>
            <Height>4.88578in</Height>
            <Width>3.0625in</Width>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>Solid</Style>
                <Width>0.25pt</Width>
              </Border>
              <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
            </Style>
          </Tablix>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>5.27578in</Height>
        <Style />
      </Body>
      <Width>3.72292in</Width>
      <Page>
        <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <ReportParametersLayout>
    <GridLayoutDefinition>
      <NumberOfColumns>4</NumberOfColumns>
      <NumberOfRows>2</NumberOfRows>
    </GridLayoutDefinition>
  </ReportParametersLayout>
  <EmbeddedImages>   
    <EmbeddedImage Name="Untitled1">
      <MIMEType>image/jpeg</MIMEType>
      <ImageData>...</ImageData>
    </EmbeddedImage>
  </EmbeddedImages>
  <Language>en-US</Language>
  <ConsumeContainerWhitespace>true</ConsumeContainerWhitespace>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>77e19f43-aab0-42f1-8ce8-f42c29f97759</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```